# "Be nice" vs. summarily closing questions for being too naive or "frustrating"

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I am puzzled by many questions being increasingly frequently closed as "off-topic", for reasons that are not immediately apparent.

Below are a couple of random examples from the past day alone. Neither is a PSQ per se, both come from posters with at least *some* history on MSE (i.e. not the 1-rep users who create a new account for every homework question), and both have *some* indication of "*own thoughts*".

(*Disclaimer: I have an answer posted to one of those questions, but that's not the point*.)

- [Integer solutions to $x^3=y^3+2y+1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2882685/integer-solutions-to-x3-y32y1):
    OP's "*own thought*" as posted was:

  > My approach:
  >
  > I tried to factorize $x^3-y^3$ as $$(x-y)(x^2 + xy + y^2)=2y+1,$$ but I know this is completely helpless. Please help me in solving this problem.

  Quite obviously, the above doesn't lead anywhere useful, as the OP themselves "*know*", and that's the reason why they are asking here. By closing the question as "*off-topic*" MSE appears to say that "*your failed attempt wasn't close enough for us to even bother*". That's not nice.
- [Quartic equation and Vieta's formulas](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2884089/quartic-equation-and-vietas-formulas/2884275): OP's "*own thought*" as posted was:

  > I evaluate these roots, but the formulas are too complicated and I wonder if there is a different solution. If we calculate the product, the solution is complicated too.

  Neither approach is a priori unreasonable, and both could be technically worked out (with enough calculation pains). But the question was about "*a different solution*", which is an entirely *on*-topic question for MSE. However, it got dismissed. Again, not nice.

  For context, one other user got suspicious because the question referenced $2018$, and asked about the source of the problem, which the OP did not answer timely. Then the question was flagged for review, which it passed with 3-out-of-3 ["*leave open*"](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/1054041) votes. Then the same user posted ["Argh!!! question and answer on this post frustrate me"](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2165?m=46231960#46231960) on [CRUDE](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2165/crude), and within 12 hours the question received the required [close votes](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2884089/timeline#history_87c2fac1-edff-4cd1-b4af-3e1c0d31d44d) and was put on hold.

Back to the point, the [MSE manifesto](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) says that "*MSE is a q&a site for people studying math at* ***any level***", and the recently discussed [SO code of conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct) says "***offer support*** *if you see someone struggling or otherwise in need of help*". Summarily closing legitimate questions with no good reason meets neither.

---

[ *EDIT* ]   As pointed out by `@JyrkiLahtonen` (thank you for the answer, and sorry for my unintentional miscue)... Just like you, I missed the point that the first question was (also) marked as `contest-math`, which made my post sound to be about contest math, which was not my intention in the least. This should address your **1**, **2**, **5** and, to make this point very clear, I am all against cheating under any guises, yet closing a question just because it happens to involve the number $2018$ is a big unwarranted stretch IMHO.

There are many enough examples of other non-contest questions being closed just for being "too naive" (per my newly sanitized title) e.g. [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2877034/291201), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2869344/291201), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2880616/291201), [4](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2868062/291201), [5](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2881413/291201), [7](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2862577/291201), [8](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2880349/291201) etc.

The concern I meant to raise was about users who had honest questions, posted in compliance with the official MSE rules, but who found themselves dismissed with a summary "*off-topic*" closure for reasons that are not spelled out in the terse closure text, and virtually never justified by the closers in comments. That's essentially telling someone who came for math help to MSE that their question is "*off-topic*" here, without offering any good reason, explanation or actionable recourse. I don't think that's "*nice*", whether CoC or not, and regardless of whether you count yourself as a "*librarian*" or a "*teacher*".

Comment: +1 - closing feels 'trigger-happy' here. Btw, am not familiar with the way the contests are run. Is it actually possible to access external media while  participating? If not, and if not ongoing, the objection is surely completely invalid? But again happy to be educated on the way contests are run if anyone can enlighten me?

Comment: "which the OP did not answer timely."  The question was posted more than 24 hours ago, the comment requesting clarification about the source was posted more than 24 hours ago, the OP was active 12 hours ago, and yet hasn't responded to the request.  Perhaps you should have said "which the OP did not answer."

Comment: In the title, you mention closing questions for being "dumb."  Could you provide an example where the question was closed for being "dumb"?  (In the two you linked to, I see no evidence of the questions being closed for being "dumb.")

Comment: I agree questions should usually not be summarily "closed".  But they often should be summarily "put on hold".  When that happens, they must be improved before being answered.

Comment: @Mehness math.SE has a policy for contest problems. if a problem is on-going, the question will be locked and existing answer will be hidden by mod until contest ends. Whether one should put a question on-hold or not is independent of its status as a "contest problem".

Comment: thanks @achillehui - did not know contests were structured such that external media could be accessed - I thought it was old-fashioned walk into a room with a pen and pencil then exit a few hrs later somewhat dazed :) But fair enough good policy on that point...

Comment: @Mehness If you browse the questions tagged ([meta-tag:contests]) here on meta, you can find both examples of such contests and also some discussions relevant to this topic.

Comment: Wow - @MartinSleziak, had a look at a few, that's terrible, wasn't aware of such brazen lack of ethics, thanks for the post!

Comment: I appreciate the willingness to discuss, but I think that the title of this question is somewhat problematic. For instance, I understand (and even use) quotation marks with different intentions depending on context, but I don't think it is a good idea to use one alongside another, where one is intended to mark an actual (close enough) quote from someone and the other is not (as far as I can see).

Comment: Furthermore, there is no explicit evidence for the close reason of the first to be related to questions being "dumb" (as another user pointed out here), and there is a fair amount of evidence that points towards the second not being closed *because* it was "frustrating": it seems to me that the frustration you allude to is a *result* of (possibly, one of) the reason(s) for why it was closed.

Comment: Seconding Aloizio's point, and thanking you to come to meta to discuss. We need more of that. After reading [Shog9's reply](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/311901/169003) to me venting my frustrations I did realize that our failure to communicate is what makes the chasm between (my current favorite neutral terms) *the librarians* and *the teachers* grow bigger. Personally I find it extremely frustrating that the teachers never come to meta. Bill Dubuque, to his credit, tried, but his style didn't really fertilize the ground for a  compromise.

Comment: I think that it is rather unfortunate that "context" is often interpreted as meaning "show what you tried".  In your two examples, I completely agree that the asker has shown what they tried to a satisfying extent.  The additional context that would improve the questions is _background_.  Why are they interested in these questions at all?  Where did they find them?

Comment: "Personally I find it extremely frustrating that the teachers never come to meta." @Jyrki, I think I'm in the "teachers" camp, and I come to meta all the time, but at some point I got tired of the losing battle with the "librarians", and after that mostly kept out of those arguments.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I suppose I'm a "librarian". IMO, the whole chasm is precisely because the "teachers" drew a line and *battled* over the very premise of "library-keeping". MSE would be in a better state if teachers could cross that line and join a discussion of how library-keeping could be done better. The loudest teacher voices professing to say anything on the topic would not even agree that one question could be better for MSE to keep than another question, and so were really just "don't do library-keeping" in disguise.

Comment: For what's worth, the first question has already attracted two close votes till now.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche `In the two you linked to, I see no evidence of the questions being closed for being "dumb."` That was just a paraphrase, arguably not the best one. Fixed now, hope you find the edit more appropriate.

Comment: @Gerry I concede to having oversimplified there. You said earlier that there are factions within factions, and that is true. I align myself with the librarians, but unlike a few others I hate dupes (and related rep farming) with passion, but will give true noobs a bit of slack etc.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo `I don't think it is a good idea to use one alongside another` You are right, thank you, the title is fixed now. `there is no explicit evidence for the close reason of the first to be related to questions being "dumb" (as another user pointed out here)` There is no explicit evidence for the close reason at all, which is part of my point. `it seems to me that the frustration you allude to is a result of (possibly, one of) the reason(s) for why it was closed` That's not the timeline I am seeing.

Comment: Re: *without offering any good reason, explanation or actionable recourse*. Well, only if you do not count the big box under the question containing a link to a more detailed explanation. It was suggested that it would be better not to have this under off-topic:
[A feature requested for the purpose of avoiding unintentional newbie-biting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/26524). Judging by the response from a Stack Exchange employee, this is unlikely to change.

Comment: @GEdgar `I agree questions should usually not be summarily "closed". But they often should be summarily "put on hold". When that happens, they must be improved before being answered.` Problem with that is that it's a lot easier to close a question than have it reopened. Don''t think that the closers get notified that the question was updated and maybe deserves a second chance, and going through the [reopen protocol on meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28692/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-volume-07-2018-today) is not obvious to most.

Comment: @GEdgar A few random examples of such questions edited after being closed, and arguably eligible for reopening, except none was [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2882298/solution-of-fracdydx-fracy-1y-2ex-x), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2876217/implicit-differentiation-related-rates), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2862323/how-to-calculate-the-angle-at-the-center-to-4-coordinates). ...Wait, #2 was even deleted since, despite having been updated.

Comment: `Problem with that is that it's a lot easier to close a question than have it reopened.... – dxiv` This has also been discussed many times. I explained my view [in this thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/26429/11619). Also take a look at thread Martin linked to three comments upstream.

Comment: @dxiv: Concerning (2) in your above comment, did you not see that it was "deleted by Community♦ 3 hours ago (RemoveAbandonedClosed)"? If you don't understand something, ask, but don't make all kinds of assumptions about other people.

Comment: FWIW I removed my downvote in response to the edit. The confusion resulting from lack of more precise commentary in relation to the "on hold" message is a recurring theme. Michael Hardy is frequently claiming the soapbox complaining about this. Search for his posts in meta for more discussion. You see, that point is frequently discussed. While it is refreshing to have new participants and new angles, argument reuse is the default reaction for many.

Comment: Also, to the extent that your complaint is directed at the loosely organized way of collecting votes to handle questionable content (not to be confused with [Jeph Jacques' fine webcomic](https://questionablecontent.net/)) see also [this thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28390/11619).

Comment: "I am all against cheating under any guises, yet closing a question just because it happens to involve the number 2018 is a big unwarranted stretch IMHO." Why do you condone that the poster continues to refuse to disclose any information regarding the source of the problem? This continued refusal is the source of the issue with the question. (Why not focus on this?)  This is also the problem with several other problems your mentioned (I did not yet check all), The thing is not that the are "too naive" but that they  lack any motivation and look a bit random.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Having them closed as "off-topic" adds another layer of confusion, and btw I agree with (and upvoted at the time) both the proposal you linked and [Jyrki's answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/26528/291201).

Comment: @quid The question meets the minimum standards set by "*how to ask*" IMHO, still it got closed as "*off-topic*" and is now marked for deletion. As for why the OP did not answer, I see that someone cleaned up in the meantime, but at some point there were a few more comments posted every couple of hours that just copy/pasted the same question of "*what is the source*" which sounded like harsh interrogation. My best guess is that the OP decided to troll the asker by simply *not* responding.

Comment: @quid Turning the tables, you are a moderator, yet chose to *not* lock the question because, of course, there was no good reason to. Yet, the question has been closed and is now headed towards deletion for the same (no good) reason.

Comment: "OP decided to troll the asker by simply not responding." So you condone that?

Comment: @quid No, but I also do not condone frustration escalating into retribution.

Comment: "you are a moderator, yet chose to not lock the question because, of course, there was no good reason to." As far as I recall the first time I saw the question it was already answer since a considerable time. As far as the asker is concerned it would have been irrelevant. That's one thing. Another thing is that another moderator had answered. Generally we try to be careful not to interfere with each other lightly. Finally, if the question is not improved  will be deleted anyway, so that's that.

Comment: "No, but I also do not condone frustration escalating into retribution." That's a misunderstanding. The question lacks context, thus  it is put on hold. The commenter informed OP what they can do to fix the question; as you requested. If this is ignored, the question will be removed. That's it.

Comment: My sense overall is that these questions likely have been put on hold because the posts are not written with very high quality, not because the level of the mathematics is too low. A high-quality post will include motivation and background, and explain the appearance of seemingly arbitrary constants such as 2018. A post that merely states a problem can be of quite low quality for this site, even if the mathematics is not trivial (e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2886961/find-a-closed-form-expression-for-sum-k-0k-frac1k1-n-1-k-choose ).

Comment: I really don't understand why example number 8 was closed/received so much downvotes.

Comment: dxiv: I'm sorry, but in your title, you created the fallacy of a false dichotomy.  I never downvote or close questions based on "dumbness" (your first term, prior to your edit), nor based on naivete, nor base on frustration.  I do vote to close PSQ's, and I am by and large "being nice".  So to me, the question is premised on a false dichotomy.  Being nice is not equivalent to letting anything go. That sort of approach: "any homework and PSQ will be answered immediately!" actually harms a learner more than it helps.

Comment: @amWhy `any homework and PSQ will be answered immediately` That's not my stand. I had hoped I made that clear when I wrote "*neither is a PSQ per se, both come from posters with at least some history on MSE ... and both have some indication of 'own thoughts'*". The only fault I can see with both those questions (and the others listed later) is that OP's "*own thoughts*" were deemed to be "not good enough" to merit MSE's attention. *That* goes against "*being nice*", as well as the stated purpose of MSE as a math q&a site "*at any level*".

Comment: dxiv *That* has been subject to your *interpretation*.  You never explain what's "good enough". I look for genuine thoughts, effort, motivation accompanying a question.  Q ["$x+ y =z$ solve for y. **My thoughts**: i thought  answer was different, but the solutions says $y=z-y,$ which I couldn't get.  Can someone show me step by step how to get y" ??? (*absence of anything tangible wrt what their result was, nor how they got it.*)  That doesn't count as including thoughts; it counts only as evading the show of effort/ thinking. Where are their workings? and what did they get (and how)?

Comment: In all these scenarios I am always amazed at the total lack of response from original asker once the question is put on-hold (and perhaps closed later) and someone else has to fight for their cause like a crusader. Why can't the asker at least come forward and present his case?

Comment: @amWhy It comes down in the end to the degree of benefit of the doubt that you are willing to allow someone. I guess it has happened to all of us at some point or another to spend time on a problem only to end up with a pile of scribbles that went nowhere. If I then were to ask for help, I would probably not feel too inclined to transcribe all of that in the question, but rather summarize it in a sentence or two, and even less inclined to post hard evidence just to prove how badly I failed in my attempts...

Comment: @amWhy ...Apparently, that would make me very suspect in the eyes of many around here, and would get the question quickly flagged as - out of all things - "off-topic". I don't find this kind of blanket rejection to be constructive or even desirable on MSE but, of course, that's just my opinion.

Comment: @amWhy I was replying very specifically to your question addressed to me in a previous comment: `You never explain what's "good enough". I look for genuine thoughts, effort, motivation accompanying a question`. That said, no worry, this was the last ping.

Comment: Then I should have said (you never answered what you think is "enough"), I look for genuine thoughts and/or effort, and/or motivation, accompanying a question.  No one is entitled to expect someone to do their work for them.  It's a two-way street of ***mutual respect*** between askers and answerers that's needed.

Comment: You mentioned a "terse closure text" that however contains a link to this [How to ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) Could you clarify what information is missing so that this could possibly be expanded? Of course, you  could also expand it yourself. (Reposted as the initial version was found lacking.)

Comment: @quid The [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and its shorter counterpart [How do I ask a good question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) both provide well-written good advice. I don't see much to add to either, and reality remains that very few posts hit *all* the points made in those, including some of the best highly-rated questions.

Comment: @quid My problem with the *terse closure text* is that it reads `which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts...` but in practice it appears to be used with the additional caveat `...provided they are smart enough and credible enough to satisfy some of our more seasoned users`.

Comment: I think that's just not what happens, at least not in the second question. The text says (my emph): "This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by **providing additional context,** [...]"  and then mentions by way of example what you quote (with further details to be found under the link). Note that it says "*includes*" before the work and attempts not, say, "is comprised of". In the specific case there even was a comment which context exactly should be added (the source).  Only OP did not bother to follow up (in fairness, now they can't).

Comment: Regarding "hit all the points made in those": I do not think that there is an expectation of that even. But as a rule of thumb for questions that clearly seem  "constructed" I'd think a source is reasonable. Generally, what exactly is expected can vary, and can be communicated via comments. Of course when comments are ignored, things become complicated. I continue to think is that this is simply indefensible, and am somewhat surprised that this is controversial.

Comment: @quid Thank you for your opinion, and I'll leave it at that. Everyone seems to focus on the "*2018*" question, but that was just one example among several. Look at the other one for example, which has been closed, then reopened (after, and presumably because of, the link here), and has now amassed $3$ close votes again. Its [timeline](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2882685/timeline) looks a bit like a tug of war, and those voting to (re)close still do not offer any reason at all why.

Comment: Thus far it is not closed again and it is not clear if it will be closed again. A clear concern (source!) was articulated there too (by Jyrki) and this was addressed if only tersely. One of the voters commented in some detail here. I think to say that they do not offer any reason at all is not an exact paraphrase of the situation. Some users demand more detailed context. I think askers, and users that want to be helpful, best adapt to this and provide that context or help the askers in coming up with it. There are no plans to lower the  standards; if anything the contrary.

Comment: @Jyrki: I don't think I like the "librarian" vs "teacher" terminology as a proxy for a position on moderation standards. While I think I am a librarian *as you mean the term*, I would identify more as a teacher by the conventional meaning. My position on quality standards is *primarily* driven to by the need to clear away the people who would use MSE for "solutions manual on demand" so that the site better attracts people who come to learn and that I can find their questions to teach them.

Comment: @Hurkyl. I agree that those terms are not very descriptive. My thinking started from trying to come up with a non-offensive term for [type 3s](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252077/5001846) with a view of inducing a good faith dialogue. You only need to look at my profile to see that I think of my role here as one of a teacher even though for the purposes of this inaccurate dichotomy (see Gerry Myerson's objection) I definitely identify as a librarian. I don't know what would be best. The other terms for those are all at least mildly derogatory.

Comment: (cont'd) While I find the antics of some of them worthy of even more offensive terms, in light of [the response from SE staff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/311901/169003), like it or lump it, the long term health of Math.SE necessitates the creation of some kind of a compromise. I can be talked into a joint effort simply to vote users like [redacted] out of the site, but what good will that do? There will come others like him.

Comment: What we need is a serious discussion, where a compromise is sought and hopefully also found. We then need to nail those theses to all Math.SE entrances. What's more, we need the moderators to agree to uphold those theses to make sure that new askers and answerers see them.

Comment: But, I'm not holding my breath. The cucumbers (current term for type 3s in Stack Overflow) won't bother to show up for any serious policy discussion. You see, that would be away from the time that could be "better" spent searching for the next low hanging fruit. May be they are scared to come to meta? For reasons other than to complain, when they are not in the mood of a serious search for a compromise. Not that I'm always in the mood to sit down and talk either. Another venue might be better, but the meta is there for this very purpose.

Comment: dxiv: Closing a question is actually harder than you think: [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28092/closed-vote-invalidated-before-triggering-review), since the close vote queue is so long. And even in the close vote queue, it is not very easy to close a question (3 "leave open" will kick the Q out of the queue). Of course the same goes for reopen queue (and Yes, I completely agree that it is hard to reopen a post). So what you can do is (1) do more reviews, and (2) go to [moderation tool](https://math.stackexchange.com/tools) to vote more.

Comment: [Another instance where close vote queue fails](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/1054852). Someone make a [wrong edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/2175388/4), thus kicking it out of the queue.

Comment: I don't know if anyone is still checking here, but [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2897943/can-we-compute-sqrt-1-sqrt-1/2897965) as gathered three close votes, and I'm not entirely sure why.

Comment: @TheoBendit This comment thread is not the place to post every complaint about every close vote on the site but here we go: a reason for these close votes might be that this very question has already been hashed and rehashed and re-re-hashed on main ad nauseam.

Answer (score 25):

This is a difficult issue, but I basically disagree with your conclusions in these two cases. Sporadic thoughts:

1. I didn't vote to put either of those questions on hold even though I saw them in the queue. I was following my private policy of keeping non-trivial questions open. If I had noticed that the first had a [contest-math](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contest-math) tag, I would have voted to put it on hold. Similarly about the second, I moved too fast. More below.
2. If someone posts a contest problem, they MUST provide a link to the source (more often than not the homepage of the contest). [We have a strict policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16774/11619) to delete questions from on-going contests. It behooves the asker to prove that the question is from an old contest. If I had voted on your first example question I would have left a comment telling exactly that. IMO the goals of the "be nice" -policy do not enter the equation here at all. We have a firm per site policy to act against all attempts at cheating in a contest.
3. The question about the zeros of a quartic is IMHO borderline. It is certainly lacking in context. The asker should have described the origin of the question (this is always the case when they cannot present partial effort). Otherwise the answerers are fumbling in the dark, guessing what tools can be used. With misgivings I decided not to vote to put that on hold, but 1) it could still actually be from a contest (the theme recurs in rapid fire contests), 2) it does not describe where the asker encountered the problem, so the level is unclear, 3) OTOH they did explain their attempt to use Vieta relations.
4. The Code of Conduct also says that *If you’re here to get help, make it as easy as possible for others to help you.* Furthermore, it also says *Be open when receiving feedback*. Neither asker quite met the first goal. This is, of course, not an excuse not to leave feedback, see the next bullet.
5. Observe that one of the voters specifically asked the asker of the latter question about the origin of the question, and raised the reasonable concern that the appearance of the number $2018$ leaves a reasonable doubt that the question might be from an on-going contest. So they left feedback, all in accordance with the "be nice" -policy.  <strike>Also observe that the asker failed to respond to this. I cannot shake the feeling that the asker, having gotten their answer, merrily copy/pasted the solution, and we will not hear from them again. I sincerely hope I'm wrong.</strike> The striked sentence is a bit off the mark given that I recently learned that the asker cannot respond because they are serving a suspension. I'm not sure what that says about their motives for this particular question?
6. So, the Code of Conduct does not grant the askers an open license to ignore all the quality constraints imposed by Math.SE. If you want to discuss/abolish/refine any given quality requirement, you should discuss the policy. Pointing fingers at users who try to uphold those standards is, frankly, a cheap shot. Looks like you are trying to use CoC as a hammer to make it more difficult to enforce the agreed upon standards rather than discussing those standards directly. I hope I'm wrong about this as well.
7. Namely, the users keen to maintain the content standards are under a lot of pressure. The dupe/LQ asking/answering is running rampant and the site is ill. The moderators discussed this in the Spring. I supported the idea to cut them some slack because without their work anarchy would prevail. They simply don't always have the time to leave more precise comments. You can take positive action and explain an asker what they should do. I frequently point them to [our guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619). Why don't you join in this effort!
8. I am somewhat unhappy with the current formulation of the CoC. For it does nothing to address the answerers. Many users in Meta.Stackexchange have expressed this concern. [My query](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/311874/169003) got a lot of positive attention, also answers providing some perspective. As the SE people said, *this document is supposed to evolve*, so I'm not overly concerned, yet. Also see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312049/169003), [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312855/169003), [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312859/169003) for other concerns.

> The eager beaver answerers (you see, I am being nice and not using the retired term to describe them) also need to do their part in restoring harmony. The excuse *I'm here just to help* does not wash unless you do your part in cleaning up. Because *Your Mommy doesn't work here!* A compromise or a war? Which is it gonna be?

---

Addendum of more sporadic thoughts (in response to the list added to the question):

- Most of those question were *missing context* at the time of the
  closure. Indeed, it seems clear to me that you have not internalized that *Off-topic -> Missing context* is just a shorthand for *Missing context*. This was thoroughly explained in one of the threads you linked to in a comment, and it is also explained in "the on hold message" (provided that you are willing to read past "off-topic").
- Consequently those closures seem totally unrelated to the "be nice" -policy.
- Personally I would not have voted to close some of them. Some of those contest math questions seemed borderline ok, but the voters who judge contest questions by the same standards as other questions have a point. I'm not in that group of librarians, but I understand their thinking and find it very much defensible. I would not have voted to put the question about Levy processes on hold simply because I don't understand the math, and cannot tell whether sufficient context is provided. But, I vote against keeping any calculus question on any excuse simply because we have plenty of near duplicates, and the calculus answerers, by and large, have a very poor track record in searching (this may be just me, let's not base a site policy on my peeves, please).
- The way the war on content quality is raging has, unfortunately but also inevitably, caused several users to dig themselves into a deep trench. Some answering machines exhibit a total disregard of all quality requirements. I confess to being a bit trigger-happy when certain names appear under answers to questionable questions. It is difficult to tell how much of a role this plays. When no amount of pleading or explaining stops these people, I don't have a choice but to seek and remove those contributions from the site any which way I can. Making it necessary to vote to close the threads in all borderline cases, downvote, and later vote to delete. **IF ONLY TO BRING THEM AND THEIR SUPPORTERS TO META TO TALK THIS OVER!!** I didn't start this war.

Comment: I concede that my last bullet is close to veering off-topic. May be I should remove it to better keep the discussion related to these two questions only?

Comment: I don't know what the term is you are retiring and not using anymore, but "ego point hunters" appears in your answer, and I would suggest to replace it as well.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo It's a reference to this discussion: [It’s time to retire the term “rep-whore”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/281787).

Comment: A fair point @Andrés. I still tend to forget that *the incentive structures in place* (rather than individual users optimizing their score) is to blame.

Comment: Thank you Jyrki.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen You mention that "We have a strict policy to delete questions from on-going contests." Is there a place where users can find this policy? I wasn't able to find anything about it in the help center or the contest-math tag description.

Comment: I wouldn't back down much, here, @JyrkiLahtonen.  Your reply is fully respectful, in answer to a question that smells like a rant and attack on users who disagree with the asker.

Comment: Thanks @amWhy. Enough many have seen it, and even if I edit some things out, the edit history will still be there for all to see. Not much point :-/ Letting it all hang out :-)

Comment: @SantanaAfton [there you go](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16774/contest-problem-policy/16775#16775)

Comment: What your post states now needs no backing down from.  I was referring in my comment to this edited version (though I have to admit, I didn't see much wrong, at all, with the first version).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen First off, thank you for the thoughtful reply, even though I may not agree on all points.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen  **2.** The quoted contest policy specifically refers to "***on-going*** *contest questions*" defined as "*publicly available*", "*time-limited*" and, of course, "*on-going*". I don't see where it "***behooves*** *the asker to prove that the question is from an old contest*". There is no indication thus far that the second question linked in my post would actually fall under the "*on-going contest questions*" category.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen **6.** Not sure what those `agreed upon standards` are supposed to mean in this context. I didn't think that "*presumed guilty until proved innocent*" would be one of them.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen **7.** I do that many times. But that wasn't the point here, and the given examples were technically compliant aleady.

Comment: @dxiv: It is in my opinion **extremely telling** that the asker kept silent after being asked **repeatedly** where the problem came from. Based on that, it is **not** presuming guilt until innocence proven, but rather closing the question **temporarily** until the asker provides assurance that it is not a cheating attempt.

Comment: @dxiv If that asker is innocent they can provide the source, and then we are left with an interesting question and no worries. If they refuse.... *The agreed upon standards* refers to [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619).

Comment: @amWhy `a question that smells like a rant` "*He who lives in a glass house shall not throw stones*". If you found anything factually incorrect in my post, then by all means point that out. Otherwise, please refrain from pointless  innuendo.

Comment: See [this list of threads](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/16774?lq=1) linked to Willie Wong's description of our contest policy. Personally [I used to apply this policy with possibly too much zeal](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27149/11619).

Comment: The discussion about contest problem [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/22415/11619) was illuminating to me. Najib Idrissi and quid raised interesting points.

Comment: @user21820 `It is in my opinion extremely telling that ...` You're entitled to your opinion, of course. Yet, that doesn't change the fact that you are casting a "*guilty until proved innocent*" doubt on the OP, based on no facts at all, except maybe their reluctance to somehow prove themselves "*not guilty*". To some, and in some cultures, your that very doubt would be perceived as downright offensive, and not worthy of a followup. Not saying that's necessariliy the case here, but maybe you shouldn't pre-judge.

Comment: @dxiv: Your claims about me are your own opinion, of course. That doesn't change the fact that you answered the question, and hence it is difficult to believe you can be 100% objective about it. Also, you are making a serious mistake by bringing up culture. In some cultures, many people consider cheating to be their right. (See [here](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/asia/china/10132391/Riot-after-Chinese-teachers-try-to-stop-pupils-cheating.html) and [here](https://www.scmp.com/news/china/society/article/2149613/fake-fingerprints-and-electronic-erasers-how-chinas-innovative)!)

Comment: @user21820 `Your claims about me are your own opinion, of course` I don't recall making any claims about you. `and hence it is difficult to believe you can be 100% objective about it` About ***what***?

Comment: @dxiv: You claimed that I cast a "guilty until proved innocent" doubt on the OP. That claim is merely your opinion, not necessarily the truth (and from my point of view your claim is false). It is difficult to believe you can be 100% objective in assessing whether the question is suitable for the site and what is the best way to deal with it.

Comment: @user21820 `You claimed that I cast a "guilty until proved innocent" doubt on the OP` Yes, indeed, and this is not a matter of "objectiveness" percentages. You wrote "*but rather closing the question temporarily until the asker provides assurance that it is not a cheating attempt*". That's ***your*** presumption of guilt upon the asker until they prove themselves innocent. `It is difficult to believe you can be 100% objective in assessing whether the question is suitable for the site` I have no idea what you mean, or insinuate, by that.

Comment: @dxiv This is not a criminal court, so *guilty until proven innocent* is not really a relevant principle. IMO it is closer to having a play reviewed by video officials in a football game (American or Association). The game is temporarily halted (the question *on hold* as opposed to *closed*), the rulebook is consulted, a call is made,  the game goes on. What is wrong with that?

Comment: @dxiv: I don't know whether you actually have problems understanding what I wrote, but there is **absolutely** no way you can say that what I wrote (that you quoted above) **logically implies** that I **presumed guilt**. (I didn't presume guilt. Neither did I presume innocence.) Do not put words into my mouth, period.

Comment: What's more. Here the spectators can overrule the ref after they made their call. That wouldn't work in football, but we do it here. Take an active role! If you see votes to put on hold a question you like, you can try and help the asker. I do that often in such a case (with varying degrees of success).

Comment: In terms of "guilty until proven innocent" - in my experience as a mathematician, the reason that a constant such as 2018 appears in a problem is usually that the problem was given in a contest, exam, or homework that was given in 2018.    In general, the appearance of arbitrary constants in mathematical theorems is not so common, and when they do appear the reason for the choice of constant can be explained. This is a collaborative site, which fundamentally entails a certain amount of discussion - an OP who declines to engage in ordinary mathematical discussion is misusing the site.

Comment: On a lighter side, wouldn't it be fun to consider SE-ified football, @JyrkiLahtonen ? in which, say,  "spectators can overrule" officials, for example, in the World Cup finals, or the NFL Superbowl! ?

Comment: LOL, @amWhy. May the loudest group of fans win!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: four of your points are about the question being a contest one. That's far from obvious. The tag was added by amwhy and not by the OP, so I fail to understand why everyone is using such tag to draw conclusions.

Comment: @MartinArgerami You do realize that I only refer to the first sample as being from a contest, and *suspect* the same from the second. In my third point I say "It could still actually be from a contest..." amWhy never edited the first sample, so I don't see your point. Anyway, I do highly suspect the second one to also be from a contest. There are several earmarks. Also the asker has had ample opportunities to set thing straight now, but never bothered. Read the comments by quid and Carl Mummert.

Comment: @MartinArgerami I am **not** using that tag to draw any conclusions. I have been semi-actively involved in organizing contests. Let me just state that it walks like a duck and talks like a duck.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Furthermore, possibly precisely due to my personal history I am more lenient towards questions about contest math than the average librarian. See [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/22416/11619). I have resigned to the fact that my wishes about special treatment of contest questions won't be granted. OTOH, if it looks like an attempt to cheat in a lilve contest, then [I will react violently](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27149/11619).

Comment: @CarlMummert: Conversely, we can invite anyone to try to come up with a natural mathematical problem (not contrived for some contest) that spits out only the number 2018. I think 2018 is too big to suffer from the law of small numbers. =) More seriously, even if the asker is not attempting to cheat, the asker's week-long suspension (3 days left) is not helping his case...

Comment: @user21820  I didn't notice that the asker is suspended! That's a wonderful excuse not to respond to amWhy's query, don't you think :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: In case people reading your comment are getting the wrong idea, the user was not suspended during the more than a day of seeing those queries and not responding but instead posting a new poor question. So, no excuse, do I think! =)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen `Personally I find it extremely frustrating that the teachers never come to meta` + the end of your edit along the same line... [Gerry's comment](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28932/be-nice-vs-summarily-closing-questions-for-being-too-naive-or-frustrating#comment122110_28932) sums it up pretty well. IMHO there is (and has long been) a disconnect between the meta and the main, as well as between the most vocal and the audience at large. My question here, for example, ended up with a positive vote balance, but a high negative comments count.

Comment: ...I believe half the CRUDE regulars posted here, while there is no such group that I am aware of on the "teachers" side (btw, "teachers", however inaccurate, could be a lot more conducive to dialog than "rep-whore", or even "eager-beaver"). If I did not get to reply to all comments (which I certainly did not), it wasn't because I was lacking answers, or conceded the points, but simply because I ran out of time and dedication to followup on each. I guess that's the same "fatigue" Gerry was alluding to.

Comment: ...Then there is that funny coincidence that each of the few times I posted an "unpopular" opinion on meta on topics even remotely related to moderation/close/delete/etc, that was followed by unexplained downvotes on random old answers of mine on the main site. I trust those do not come from the same users who, instead, made their points here in plain view, but it still shows that there are *other* users who have grown schooled to believe that drive-by-downvoting as retribution is somehow civic behavior.

Comment: ...Having said all that, I just noticed today a couple of new-user questions with less-than-perfect "own thoughts" that were still welcome and received hints/answers. Might be a fluke, or maybe this newly introduced [new contributor indicator - be nice and check out our CoC](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314287/come-take-a-look-at-our-new-contributor-indicator?cb=1) could be at fault ;-) Either way, I'll be taking a break to [camp 4](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late/252077#252077) for a while now.

Comment: @dxiv Not denying that currently meta is largely dominated by the librarians. That infamous post describing camps 1-4 does say the same: groups 1 and 3 have all the moderation power, but only group 1 is using it. And, if the responses I got at Meta.SE are to be believed this problem is worse on StackOverflow. This is why I have toyed with the idea of looking for another venue for "peace negotiations".

Comment: When camp3's come to meta only one or two at a time, they are admittedly at a disadvantage. Their complaints are easy to shoot down simply by starting with "this theme has been discussed in threads 1,2,3 back in 2011". The users who don't search for dupes in main as their first reaction, don't do it in meta either. It is not entirely unlike a layperson arguing with an army of experienced politicians (if not lawyers).

Comment: And, when I complain about these themes in main, and downvote, explaining my reasons in a comment. The comments I receive show disbelief if anything. And also seem to lead to "sympathy"-upvotes, but that is as difficult to prove as you getting drive-by-downvotes as a consequence of the discussion in this thread.

Comment: @dxiv So, to summarize, I don't like the fact that you had to fight this alone in meta. But I cannot place the blame on anyone else other than the non-participants. Even though I understand to some extent why they are feeling reluctant to join in.

Comment: For example, if you look at the string of my four last comments under the question, the only one getting any upvotes is the one that continues to point fingers. The olive branch business is not exactly thriving here.

Comment: Or, if Meta is dominated by type-1s, then similarly the type-3s enjoy a home field advantage in Main.

Comment: @dxiv votes on discussions on meta do not mean an agreement with the content, but rather express whether or not it is a relevant subject for meta. For example I did not dv your post, even though as Jyrki said it's pretty repetitive with other posts and to a considerable part was based on false premises. On 'while there is no such group that I am aware of on the "teachers" side' it seems to me it is mostly because if it's about other peoples posts and threads that group is not really motivated to do much, they care about their posts, and mostly just that.

Comment: @dxiv if you believe to be affected by inappropriate votes, please, report this in the intended way. For the current case it seems to me there is nothing egregious. (That's visible from public data.) I'd say at best two votes (this excludes the directly affected post since increased voting on this is rather normal), one of which *maybe* questionable but also justifiable (the other is in a thread with many dv'ed answers). The answers were not  old either, but rather among your then most recent answers. OTOH, you received an upvote on an old answer in that time span too. Gives maybe a net win:-)

Comment: To be clear I do not condone any form of voting motivated by meta disagreements. However, a user posting to meta does naturally draw some attention to them, which can result in votes that arise in a semi-natural way. It might be a good idea to force one-self not to vote at all in such cases, which I usually try to practice myself, but that's not evident either. However, a couple of votes after a meta-appearance is not necessarily that surprising. To sum up, we do take this seriously, but I would ask for some realism and not to exaggerate such claims. @dxiv

Comment: @dxiv  I think you're hardly in a position to claim that your post represents an "unpopular" opinion.  Read the net votes.  So I would, if I were you, suspect biased upvotes, rather than blame any downvotes you've received since you posted this on "drive by downvoting".  Of course, we are each prone to think that the upvotes we get are deserved due to our brilliance.  We are each prone to think that the every downvote we get is "unjustified" and cast "out of spite."  That doesn't mean that reality necessarily agrees with our own perceptions.

Comment: @Jyrki  Perhaps you've allowed others to convince you that you applied prohibitions against current contest question, or potentially current (if an asker refuses multiple times to respond to questions asking for the source of a problem).  I just want to share that your work in that realm was "Goldilock-friendly": Just right. (Not too soft, not too harsh, but just right).

Comment: @quid Granted, the backlash was milder this time around, yet it's still a pattern. Last time for example I got about 15 random downvotes spread over several days around 2/20/18 after posting a few comments such as [1](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27918/is-deleting-a-question-while-it-is-still-on-hold-too-quick#comment113657_27918) and [2](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27901/how-to-explain-this-string-of-downvotes#comment113582_27901). Didn't think (and not going) to waste mods' time about it, yet I find such practices unwarranted and pointless.

Comment: @dxiv since I am a curious person I had to check. The factual history seems less drastic than your recollection thereof, and you may have mixed up the timeline a bit. That said, I think it is undeniably true that there can be a correlation and even causation between showing up on meta and receiving some (negative) votes. I'd prefer if this was minimized, and I left some comments in chat about that earlier.  However, the causation might sometimes be less direct than you make it look.

Comment: There is a difference between. "I disagree with this user. There, I'll downvote them." and "I disagree with that user. I wonder what do they contribute. Let me check. I don't like that either. Downvote." Arguably the latter is not ideal either since it might be hard to control for ones own bias and I try to avoid to act in this way personally. But the two are not the same, and there is a spectrum in between. To be sure, the former also happens (unfortunately), but generally it seems not at all always  the former.  @dxiv

Comment: How does one assist with the 'cleaning up'? I am sure I have inadvertently contributed to cleanup load...