# The unofficial 2018 elections nomination post

Tags: discussion, election

There is a moderator election about to happen; we shall elect two new moderators that will reinforce the team.

The procedure dictates that candidates self-nominate (this is not yet possible). However, experience has shown that some external encouragement can be useful, whence this thread.

Some guidelines:

- Don't nominate Asaf Karagila.<sup>1</sup>
- One nomination per answer.
- In case there could be confusion, link to the profile.
- Try to give some details, don't only post a name.
- Even if you do not like some nominee, try to show restraint about it. Critical points can be raised. But this is not a thread to "grill" potential candidates, before they even decided to run.

Note that this is not an official thread. Everybody that wants to be a candidate must go through the official process. "Accepting" or "declining" a nomination here, does not mean anything in the end.

---

<sup>1</sup> The point is, don't nominate somebody that said they do not want to be nominated. If you want to approach them do so elsewhere.

Comment: I am Asaf Karagila and I approve these rules.

Comment: Is there a straightforward way to know which other users don't want to be nominated? Links to previous nomination threads, perhaps? (Though presumably some of them may have changed their minds since then...)

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist no, not really. I think the old threads that'd be the best source of information. I agree that somebody could change their mind. But for example,  Martin Sleziak said if ever they change their mind they'll self-nominate and there is no need for further nomination. Those two Asaf and Martin are the only cases I am aware of that excluded it so clearly for the future too. (I might very well forget somebody though.)

Comment: That’s a shame. I would’ve liked to nominate Martin. I hope Martin reconsiders this time.

Comment: Good luck everyone!

Comment: Request to everyone not to "unofficially" nominate Xander sir : he has politely declined my request to nominate him. @quid Are there any situations where I, or any other math/meta user, can be of help during the elections?

Comment: @Asaf Hehe.${}$

Comment: @Andrés: Well... you know... :P

Answer (score 31):

## I nominate [Aloizio Macedo](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/users/59234/aloizio-macedo).

He has been a very active member in meta (especially in the past 1-2 years). He is always balanced, and is willing to listen to different opinions. Some examples [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28390/is-crude-healthy/28406#28406) and [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27918/is-deleting-a-question-while-it-is-still-on-hold-too-quick/27929#27929)

I think he will be a good addition to the moderator team and hope this post gives him enough encouragement.

Comment: Thanks for the nomination! I gladly accept it.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo Congratulations and Good Luck for the run!

Answer (score 28):

## I nominate **[Zachary Selk](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/223391/zachary-selk)**.

While he didn't quite win the last time, I think he would make a good moderator, and I hope that the last few months didn't dissuade him from trying again.

Also relevant, his [2017 Moderator Election Q&A - Questionnaire answers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27121/622).

Comment: Thank you for the kind words! I accept this nomination and definitely will run again.

Comment: Where can I find this nomination? I feel that I have lost it.

Comment: @AndresMejia: Unfortunately, Zach withdrew his nominated and deleted his account... :(

Comment: oh wow I did not see that coming. I suppose that is the comment above mine then!

Comment: @Andres: Yup...

Comment: @AsafKaragila: ...And this makes me wonder: would someone who takes major decisions so abruptly have been a good moderator? A solid emotional balance is an underestimated quality for this kind of occupation.

Comment: @AlexM.: I think that this outcome came out of left field.